# spark-cmd not found when trying to run Spark in Rstudio

Tags: r, apache-spark, rstudio

I am following the instructions found [here on rbloggers](http://www.r-bloggers.com/installing-and-starting-sparkr-locally-on-windows-os-and-rstudio/) to set up spark on a redhat machine. I want to use Spark in RStudio.

I have downloaded `spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6` and followed the instructions as and put the following line in a script in RStudio:

```
# Setting SPARK_HOME
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "~/Downloads/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6")

# Setting library path
.libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib"), .libPaths()))

library(SparkR)

# create a spark context
sc <- sparkR.init(master = "local")
```

But the last line returns the following error:

> Launching java with spark-submit command ~/Downloads/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-submit   sparkr-shell /tmp/RtmpSwsYUW/backend_port3752546940e6
>
> sh: ~/Downloads/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-submit: No such file or directory

I have tried every solution on the internet before asking this. For example:

- JAVA_HOME and SPARK_HOME are set.
- Giving `spark-submit` executable by `chmod a+x spark-submit.cmd` (and also `chmod u+w spark-submit.cmd`) and did not work. (*of course I was in the correct library*)
- Tried `spark-shell` in terminal and it works (returns a working shell ins scala)
- Adding this before initialization:

  ```
    Sys.setenv("SPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"=" - - master yarn-client sparkr-shell")
  ```

The only issue I can think of now, is that there is no `sparkr-shell` in the directory. It is just `sparkr.cmd` and `sparkr2.cmd`. Now I am wondering is it related to spark version that I downloaded? Should I install hadoop first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SparkR` invokes Spark through `system2`, which quotes the command using `shQuote` (see `?system2` and `?shQuote`). This means that the `~` doesn't get expanded.

Just specify the full path:

```
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "/home/<youruser>/Downloads/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6")
```

Or do the path expansion yourself:

```
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = path.expand("~/Downloads/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6"))
```

The `.cmd` files are for Windows, by the way, so they're not relevant.